# Apex repeat data should show data in two coulms

Tags: visualforce

I Want display records with in repeat tag in two columns
I don't the to use the standard UI of salesforce

Can i know how to display repeat data in two columns

Comment: Have you tried anything ? The VF repeat element does not render salesforce classic UI,  that entirely depends on the HTML or other VF components you choose to use. So, it's not clear what you are struggling with. Can we see your code, or an image of your current result and how it is not what you expect it to be ?

Answer (score 2):

If its not too late for you, you can create a Wrapper class which will have 2 variables of representing one row.

```
public class AccWrapper{
public Account colOneAcc{get;set;}
public Account colTwoAcc{get;set;}

public AccWrapper(Account one, Account two)
{
  this.colOneAcc = one;
  this.colTwoAcc = two;
}

public List<AccWrapper> getAllAccIn2Columns()
{
List<AccWrapper> accList = new List<AccWrapper>();
List<Account> myLocalList = [select name, billingaddress from Account])
for(Integer i=0; i<myLocalList.size(); i++)
{
accList.add(new AccWrapper(myLocalList[i],myLocalList[++i]);
}
return accList;
}
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<table>

<apex:repeat value="{!AllAccIn2Columns}" var="accs">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<!-- put your headers -->
<tr><td>{!accs.colOneAcc.Name}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{!accs.colOneAcc.BillingAddress}</td></tr>
</table>
</td>

<td>
<table>
<!-- put your headers -->
<tr><td>{!accs.colTwoAcc.Name}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{!accs.colTwoAcc.BillingAddress}</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

I hope I was not confusing!

Comment: I want display the records in the below format

Comment: record1             record2                                                                                                   
              record3             record4

Comment: Updated my answer, check now!

Comment: The header names are dynamic i have repeat inside repeat

Comment: So use dynamic values, <th>{!parentRepeatVar.Label}</th> this this.